# How would different antler styles impact balance in humanoids?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races

I’m designing a feylike race where more dominant females develop antlers to display their place in the hierarchy. However, I haven’t decided exactly how they’re going to sit yet or if the style that I’m most interested in would alter their balance too much.

Option 1: Standard upward-oriented deer antler

Option 2: Laid down along the top of the head, similar to Eld’s Deer

Option 3: Fallow deer-style antler, in either orientation

Comment: Balance isn't such a big deal in the sense that these will likely be 99% symmetrical. However, what it does do (for heavy antlers) is alter their center of gravity upward, making them easier to topple. Probably want to stay away from moose antlers and Irish-elk-style stuff. If they live in palaces, the ceiling heights are probably sufficient.

Comment: Adding to what @JohnO said, it also changes humanoid skeletons and muscles. It's not just the weight of the antlers (assuming they're more than a couple of prongs), but also the inertia created when the head is moved. This will require thicker vertebrae, thicker shoulder bones, and thicker neck and shoulder muscles. This is another reason why balance and style are irrelevant. The animal must be designed to accommodate the weight and distribution - unless you simply declare it to be so, which is your prerogative as a worldbuilder. Do you need a scientifically plausible answer?

Comment: now you need giant irish elk antler for a the turn to fast and get a broken neck situation.

Comment: is there any actual (physical) use of the antlers or are they purely aestetic/cosmetic/social? Without physical usage you could make them from less dense materials or have them be hollow. That would reduce the weight and any balance issues by a lot

Comment: Have you never worn a large helmet? Balance is adjusted based on proprioception, which would take antlers into account.

Answer (score 1):

[Antlers are commonly 1 kg (2.2 lbs) each in red deer](https://www.wildlifeonline.me.uk/animals/article/red-deer-antlers). This means they would be really annoying for a humanoid race if analogous.

However, *presumably* the race is not jousting with it.

---

An **easy** fix is them being mostly made out of cartilage for structure

[Density comparison:](https://itis.swiss/virtual-population/tissue-properties/database/density/)

Cartilage average: 1 100 kg/m³ (barely varies too)

[Bone average](https://www.aqua-calc.com/page/density-table/substance/bone): 1 850 kg/m³

---

You can also make them hollow as they don't do anything physical. If so, it makes sense to possibly make them pneumatic as well.

---

Also if they are magical, they can have effective negative density materials in their antlers.

---

Answer (score 0):

As long as they don't go up too far, they wouldn't affect balance too much, seeing as they'd be the same on each side of the head. They might be heavy, but if they're magical, you could hand-wave the weight away ─ e.g. fey magic prevents them from being an impediment, or they're made of a magical material that doesn't weigh anything.